# AWS Kibana access control after creating AWS ES(elasticsearch)

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, aws-elasticsearch

I tried to access to Kibana after creating ES.

```
https://vpc-search-xxxxxxxxx.ap-northeast-2.es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/
```

but the browser says `this website can't be reached`
I specified my ip address at security group to allow to access but still no response.
I would appreciate any info I can refer. thanks.

Comment: What is the [access policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-createupdatedomains.html#es-createdomain-configure-access-policies) on your cluster. More specifically, are you using an IP-based policy?

Comment: @kdgregory  I am using SecurityPolicy which is ip-based and IAM too. I know I can specify ip on access policy at elasticsearch but the system says I need to use SecurityPolicy instead of specifying ipaddress there

Comment: @kdgregory probably because I am using VPC but I got no options to choose no VPC

Comment: So the ES cluster is running in the VPC? That was a rather important point to leave out of your original post. Are you able to connect from an instance running in the VPC? If yes, then you're going to need some proxy to expose access to the Internet.

Comment: @kdgregory oh right.. I didn't know what I am doing. actually I created another cluster for ip-based policy. but maybe using VPC is safer

Comment: Perhaps. Amazon certainly prefers it, since it reduces the number of public IPs in use. I was wondering why I didn't consider putting our ES clusters into the VPC, then I looked at the [doc history](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/document-history.html) and discovered that VPC wasn't an option before October of this year. At this point I'm not sure that I want to put the effort in to move our cluster.

Comment: @kdgregory right that's why I was struggling with it. it's the recent update feature so not many docs to refer. anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have access to the subnets associated with your ElasticSearch cluster - preferably use a VPN connection, otherwise use the public subnets.

**Be careful** if using public subnets - make sure your Security Groups restrict access from the public internet.

Also make sure the Access Policy on the cluster allows access:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [ "es:ESHttpGet", "es:ESHttpPut", "es:ESHttpPost", "es:ESHttpHead"],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:domain/mydomain/*"
    }
  ]
}
```